# Unity - Move object until point

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm using the code below to move a Ball to determined point. But, the ball are "teleporting" to there, how can i roll the ball until the point ?

```
void Update(){
            if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0) && EventSystem.current.currentSelectedGameObject != ButtonDiminuir && EventSystem.current.currentSelectedGameObject != ButtonAumentar &&
       EventSystem.current.currentSelectedGameObject != BarraForca) {
                    transform.position = Vector3.Lerp(transform.position, new Vector3(transform.position.x, transform.position.y, -9.0424f), 2 * Time.deltaTime);
                    Anim.Play("Kick_Up");
            }
}
```

Comment: Use a delay between each position change.

Comment: [https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Vector3.Lerp.html](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Vector3.Lerp.html) this is exactly what you want

Comment: Add a coefficient to the multiplication like this : transform.position += Vector3.forward * 0.05f *Time.deltaTime;

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it like this using [`Vector3.Lerp`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Vector3.Lerp.html) :

```
Vector3 startPosition;
Vector3 endPosition;
var speed = 10.0;

transform.position = Vector3.Lerp(startPosition, endPosition, speed * Time.deltaTime);
```

or using [`Vector3.MoveTowards`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Vector3.MoveTowards.html)

```
// The step size is equal to speed times frame time.
float step = speed * Time.deltaTime;

// Move our position a step closer to the target.
transform.position = Vector3.MoveTowards(transform.position, target.position, step);
```

Comment: Note that using the first snippet like this, it will barely move! `Lerp` interpolates between the start and end position dependin on the 3rd parameter (between 0 and 1). Time.deltaTime depends on the framerate and is usually something like `1/60 s` => You set the interpolation always to fixed on `10 * 1/60` = `1/6`. It never reaches `1`. On start you need a `passedTime = 0` before each step do `passedTime+= Time.deltaTime`. Than in the `Lerp` use this instead `Vector3.Lerp(start, end, speed * passedTime)`

Comment: I'll try and come back i'll bring answers

Comment: Z3RP, i think you code works. But the ball kind of just does a step for Update(), there is a way that runs at once in the first Update() call ? I will update the code of my question

Comment: @L.Th In your Update Method you set the end and start position everytime update is called new. Try to set it at the start and set it to null at the end :)

Comment: woooow ! Very nice. it Works! Thank you very much !

Answer (score 2):

If you want to roll the ball, use `AddForce()` instead `transform.position`.

First, add `Rigidbody` and `Sphere Collider` to your ball game object.

Then try this code:

```
public Vector3 targetPoint;
public float forceAmount;

...

void Update()
{
    Vector3 force = ((targetPoint - transform.position).normalized * forceAmount * Time.smoothDeltaTime);
    GetComponent<Rigidbody>().AddForce(force);
}
```

Also, if you want to ball stops immediately when arrive to target point, you can set `GetComponent<Rigidbody>().velocity` to 0 when `targetPoint - transform.position = 0`

I hope it helps you.

Comment: I tried with `AddForce()`, but it doens't work for me, i'll try this way like you showed me, and later i'll bring some answers