# Make a sprite move towards another. Don't need rotation similarly to the scratch point an follow. C#

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

i looked for a while and cant find anything. I don't want a full rotation, path find enemy AI. Just a script that will make one move towards the other. Like the scratch point towards "sprite1" then move 10 steps. i can only find complicated things. The actually unity tutorial tells you how to make it follow the mouse but that's it. this is in c# on unity. i am also an absolute beginner. This is also in a 2d landscape not 3d.

thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Unity - Move object until point](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52311916/unity-move-object-until-point)

Answer (score 0):

**1. Using direction vectors**

The [direction](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WNaxtPTMqSo&list=PLW3Zl3wyJwWOpdhYedlD-yCB7WQoHf-My&index=3&t=0s) vector is always: targetPosition - selfPosition

```
void MoveTo(Vector3 targetPosition){
   Vector3 direction = targetPosition - transform.position;
   transform.Translate(direction * speed * Time.deltaTime);
}
```

**2. Using Lerp:**

you can also use [Vector3.Lerp](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Vector3.Lerp.html) (or any other interpolation method):

```
Vector3.Lerp(fromPosition, toPosition, step)
```

Comment: First of all this is not a 3d landscape (sorry didn't mention that). 2nd of all like i did say, i am an absolute beginner and don't know much, so this code doesn't make since and i have no idea how to put it into context.

Comment: Unity is a 3d engine. even in 2d mode it just locks the Z.
i tried to make them as generic as possible so if you hook MoveTo into your update it will work.

i do advice following a C# Crash Course before unity. RbWhitaker blog is great.